# How can I capture the label value of my chronometer

Tags: c#, .net

I'm doing a chronometer in C# and I know how to stop the timer but the thing that I really need is to stop only the label value and let the timer running.

The only thing that I found is to make my label this way:

```
myLabel.Visible = False;
timer1.Stop();
```

But I don't want to make it invisible or Stop the timer, I just want to capture the timer value in the label and let the timer running.

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here. A label does not provide any timing functionality. You need to stop whatever means you are using to update the label from updating, or adjust your object model such that it no longer gets updated by whatever is running the timer. There's a lot of solutions, but you're approaching this from the wrong angle.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know how long something takes, use the stopwatch class, timers are used for their onelapsed events. To the the amount of time on a stopwatch use:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
long timepassed = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've an event on the timer that triggers every x seconds and updates the label, you just need to add some logic to this event to prevent the label from being updated if "you don't want it to be".  You can leave the timer running.